# Share files on BitBar

Tags: bitbar

We just started testing with BitBar to see if it will fit our needs with mobile development testing. A member of the team uploaded an Android file for testing, but nobody else can see that file on their file library. How do we share files so that all members of team can test?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [access groups](https://cloud.bitbar.com/#user/access-groups), create a new access group with scope `Account`.
Then you go to Files Library and share the file to the created access group. This way all users within the same account can access the file.